# How can I generate PDFs with the language “Khmer”?

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, tcpdf, pdf-reader

For an international website with bilingual picture books, we would like to generate PDFs also translated into Khmer.
Currently we are using “tcpdf” to generate the PDFs, and the fonts Noto Khmer and Noto Sans. In the generated PDF, some characters are displayed incorrectly.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Is it an issue with the PDF generator or is there another PDF reader that might display it correctly?

We tried different readers (Edge; Acrobat Reader; Foxit…). It looks different, but incorrect in each reader.

[How it should look like](https://ibb.co/Fx5RR2d)

[How it currently looks like (note the little pluses and minuses beneath the characters)](https://ibb.co/JRDCY1k)

This is the PDF with wrong characters: [www.bilingual-picturebooks.org/file/khmer_with-wrong-characters.pdf](http://www.bilingual-picturebooks.org/file/khmer_with-wrong-characters.pdf)

The weird thing is that the PDF still contains the correct information. If you copy & paste the text from PDF into a Word document, it is displayed correctly again. As the PDFs also contain images, this is not a suitable workaround.

Thanks in advance!